# How to close connection after doing a "View/Edit" of a table

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

In pgAdmin 4, after I right-click on a table and choose "View/Edit data", I cannot figure out how to close that new connection. If I try to "Delete/Drop" the database, it says:

> Error. Database is being accessed by other users: DETAIL ...

I searched in vain for how to close this connection. There is probably a really simple way of doing this, but I am a new user to pgAdmin.

The only way that I can now drop the database is to close pgAdmin and re-open it.